# What is the meaning and purpose of the parallelism argument in core.async pipelines?

Tags: clojure, core.async

There are three kinds of parallel [pipelines](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/pipeline) in core.async: `pipeline`, `pipeline-blocking`, and `pipeline-async`. The first argument of these functions is `n`, the ‘parallelism’ of the pipeline.

What is the meaning of this argument?

How does it influence the behaviour of each kind of pipeline? What is a good default value for parallelism? When and why would I increase or decrease that value? What if there are multiple such pipelines in a running program?

Comment: Saw some interesting input on the Clojure Jira about this today: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC-163

Answer (score 2):

[The source](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/2afc2dc5102f60713135ffca6fab993fb35809f0/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L500) is informative:

> ```
>    (dotimes [_ n]
>      (case type
>            :blocking (thread
>                       (let [job (<!! jobs)]
>                         (when (process job)
>                           (recur))))
>            :compute (go-loop []
>                                (let [job (<! jobs)]
>                                  (when (process job)
>                                    (recur))))
>            :async (go-loop []
>                              (let [job (<! jobs)]
>                                (when (async job)
>                                  (recur))))))
> ```

`n` here is the parallelism argument provided; it thus controls the number of threads (in blocking mode) or `go-loop`s (in compute or async mode).

What constitutes a "good default value" depends on your load profile, hardware resources, &c -- if a job is blocking on network access you can potentially have more of them than you have CPUs, whereas if it's blocking on CPU, more threads than cores you expect to be available is a waste; if your bottleneck is local disk I/O, then a number of details well beyond the scope of this question (spinning platters or NVRAM? Are different processes' access needs spread across platters?) become relevant.

In general: Use the same judgment, and experience, and tuning/measurement techniques you would apply to thread-pool sizing generally.

Comment: One important non-obvious thing that’s missing here – if my understanding is correct –, is that one of these is not like the others. In `pipeline` and `pipeline-blocking`, parallelism does indeed control the number of workers as you say, and all of these considerations apply. But in `pipeline-async` how many and what kind of workers there are is not determined by this parameter, instead what it does is control the number of async job dispatchers – and that number seems unimportant. So it seems to me that with `pipeline-async` there is never a reason to pass as `n` anything other than 1 or 2.

Comment: In `pipeline-async`, it's expected that the function given will return immediately, but cause a result to be written to the channel it's passed (and close that channel) at some later time, so that's quite right.

Comment: To add to what Charles said, I've used `pipeline-async` to have a pipeline that pools 60 connections to an async DB.